# windows 10- atom-live-server not starting

Tags: atom-liveserver

[Whenever i click the start server button as shown in the image nothing happens and the server does not start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwHrf.png)
I have installed atom-live-server on my laptop, but the server is not starting. I am trying to start the server from atom. I have checked for any incompatible packages view in Toggle command palette but it shows every package is fine and compatible. Please help..
I am working with Windows 10 64 bit configuration.

Comment: What errors are you seeing?

Comment: No errors nothing at all..

Comment: So what is your indication that it is not working?

Comment: Don't use unrelated tags for your questions.

Comment: when i click the start atom-live-server on atom nothing happens.

Comment: The server is not opening in my web browser

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+l inserts the character ø on Windows.

Comment: Menu: Packages / atom-live-server / start server starts the server. but does not open a page automatically unless the file is called index.html and sits in the root of the folder. This is standard behavior for a webserver.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and here is what helped me: To use the package you’ll need to have a project folder added to the Project sidebar. From here go to Packages > atom-live-server > Start Server and a preview of your site will open up in your default browser. If you need to stop the server again go to Packages > atom-live-server > Stop Server. I opened a separate folder for the project and the file is now loading in the live server.